# How to display String of Json in jsp table

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have searched every where, but can't find the help I need.

In my servlet I receive a String containing JSON data. These data are rows from a database and contains this:

```
[{"note_id":1,"title":"Homework","text":"Math ex. 15, 16, 17.","color":"Yellow","datetime":""}]
```

My problem is that I'm not able to show these data on a html table using jstl.

This is what I get:
[image]

(I'm getting stressed and can't figure out how to solve this).

Servlet code (post method):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    .
    .
    .
    String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("* JSON string contains:  * " + output); //prints the string with json data successfully

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<ArrayList<Note>> mapType = new TypeReference<ArrayList<Note>>() {};
    ArrayList<Note> jsonToList = objectMapper.readValue(output, mapType);

    request.setAttribute("allNotesOfUser", jsonToList);

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Notes.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

jsp code (just the table part):

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Id </th>
                <th> Title </th>
                <th> Text </th>
                <th> Color </th>
                <th> Date/Time </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${allNotesOfUser}" var="pp">
                <tr>
                    <td><${pp.note_id}</td>
                    <td><${pp.title}</td>
                    <td><${pp.text}</td>
                    <td><${pp.color}</td>
                    <td><${pp.datetime}</td>
                </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Note entity:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Note {
    private int note_id;
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private String color;
    private String datetime;


    public Note(int note_id, String title, String text, String color, String datetime){
        this.note_id = note_id;
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color;
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    public Note(){
        super();
    }

    public int getNote_id() {
        return note_id;
    }
    public void setNote_id(int note_id) {
        this.note_id = note_id;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }


    public String getDatetime() {
        return datetime;
    }
    public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but I tried to insert `<c:out value="" />` in my JSP code, so it looked like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${allNotesOfUser}" var="pp">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${pp.note_id}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pp.title}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pp.text}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pp.color}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${pp.datetime}" /></td>
                </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

So now it's working:
[image]

Here is a link for some reference of the [c:out](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm)

(Now i'll just continue and get stuck somewhere else T-T crying XD)

Comment: any idea if structure of json is unknown?

Answer (score 0):

simple way you can send the Note entity to jsp page and print it. and you can also use JSON object bt bst way with JSON object you have to use java script. but you can also use `com.google.gson.JSONObject` for resolve this problem.